# Toggle between three classes

Tags: javascript, toggle

My question refers to the flyout menu on my website [usaletsgo.de](https://www.usaletsgo.de). It is the red flyout in the upper left part of the site.

There are two pages, but I would like to add a third one. By flipping to page 2, all list elements of page 1 are toggled from .visible to a css class .hidden. By flipping to page 1, the same happens to all list elements of page 2.

CSS is as follows:

```
.visible{
display:block;
}

.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

JS and HTML code:

```
<script>
function switch(){
$('.toggle').toggleClass('visible hidden');
};
</script>


<li class="toggle visible">Factory Butte </a></li>
<li class="toggle visible">Moonscape Overlook </a></li>
<li class="toggle visible">Wedge Overlook </a></li>
<li class="toggle visible">Fantasy Canyon </a></li>
<li class="toggle visible">Hamburger Rocks </a></li>

<li class="toggle hidden">Leprechaun Canyon </a></li>
<li class="toggle hidden">Canyon X </a></li>
<li class="toggle hidden">Paria Canyon </a></li>
<li class="toggle hidden">Gold Butte NM </a></li>
<li class="toggle hidden">Vermilion Cliffs NM </a></li>

<li class="toggle visible"> <a href="javascript:switch()">Page 2</a></li>
<li class="toggle hidden"> <a href="javascript:switch()">Page 1</a></li>
```

This maybe not be the most sophisticated code but it works (and I am a beginner with Javascript).

How can I add a third page?

Comment: Use three `<ul>`s, one for each page, and start with the first being visible and the other two hidden. Next, keep a variable that stores which ul is currently visible. Upon a click on "nächste Seite", you increase the variable, then turn the `<ul>`s invisible/visible based on the new value.

Comment: Start by renaming your function from the reserved word switch

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. 
The code has some nifty tricks you can use
For example it does not care how many menus there are

```js
$(function() {
  var $uls = $("#menu ul"), len = $uls.length; 
  $("#menu a").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // the link is abused to show a hand. We could use a span and cursor:pointer
    var vis = $(this).closest("ul").index()+1; // which UL does the link belong to?
    if (vis>=len) vis=0;
    $uls.hide().eq(vis).show(); // show the relevant ul
  }).eq(len-1).click(); // show the first (click the last link) when loading
  $("#menu").show(); // reveal (to not show all and then hide)
});
```

```css
#menu { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Factory Butte</li>
    <li>Moonscape Overlook</li>
    <li>Wedge Overlook</li>
    <li>Fantasy Canyon</li>
    <li>Hamburger Rocks</li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Leprechaun Canyon</li>
    <li>Canyon X</li>
    <li>Paria Canyon</li>
    <li>Gold Butte NM</li>
    <li>Vermilion Cliffs NM</li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Bla Canyon</li>
    <li>Canyon Bla</li>
    <li>Paria bla</li>
    <li>Gold bla NM</li>
    <li>Bla Cliffs NM</li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, thx. One problem: links to list items do not work (see website). If I remove the '(' from function, links work but pagination doesn´t. I put the function in the head. Could you please assist? Thx again.

Comment: Ah. Yes. Try #menu a.nav and give the 3 links a class of nav

Comment: Thx. Now I messed up something and trying to find out what. Nothing visible at all anymore ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you.

With a little additional help from a friend it´s working.